# Why are there (seemingly) unnecessary "à"s and "de"s in these sentences?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

In the sentence

> Parce que la préposition à indique un mouvement

Is the *à* necessary? Can't you just say

> Parce que la préposition indique un mouvement

In another sentence which has a different context

> Les devoirs sont à faire à la maison

Does the *à* beside *faire* mean "To be done" in this sentence?

And my last question, does adding *de* in a sentence like

> La forme la plus correcte est de lire à la page cinq

(I was reading a few forum posts about the difference of à, en, and dans, and this is one of the few answers replying to someone's examples)

Indicate a sort of quotation? Because without *de*, it still looks right to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the first sentence, you must consider "préposition à" like a noun. Personnally I would write "à" in italic in this case to show that it is not used as a preposition. Indeed, not all preposition indicate a movement: this is a specificity of "à".

> Parce que la préposition *"à"* indique un mouvement.
> Parce que le *"à"* indique un mouvement.
>
> Because "to" indicates a movement. (I apologize if my English is not correct)

for the second sentence, your interpretation is correct: 'à faire = to be done'

for the third sentence, you could also write

> La forme la plus correcte est: "lire à la page cinq"

but otherwise you need the "de" like in :

> Il est correct de faire...
> Il est important de faire...
> Il est mal de faire

etc

Comment: « à faire » se traduit plutôt par « to be done ».

Comment: merci pour le commentaire: j'ai corrigé

Answer (score 2):

The "à" is definitely necessary in the sentence because it is the whole point of it. Read it like:

> Parce que la préposition « à » indique un mouvement

In the second sentence, *faire à* is indeed to be done:

> *Les devoirs sont à faire à la maison* : Assignments are to be done at home (i.e. they are homework).

*De* is required in the third sentence as it is written.

> La forme la plus correcte est de lire à la page cinq